# edit value of existing variable xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a variable which I set the value. Thereafter, in a loop, I would like to edit this variable and use it in the next iteration. Is there any way I can edit the value in the variable? Thanks!

```
<xsl:variable name="numberVariable" select="5">
----loop----
$numberVariable = $numberVariable+2
----End loop----
```

Comment: variables in xslt are misname and are actually constants, the only way that I am aware of doing this is to use recursion.

Comment: any links on examples to do it?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you explained what is your *real* purpose here. BTW, if you referring to `xsl:for-each`, it is not a loop, and it has no "next iteration".

Answer (score 2):

> in a loop, I would like to edit this variable and use it in the next iteration. Is there any way I can edit the value in the variable?

**The answer is negative**:

XSLT is a functional language and this, among other things means that a variable's value, once defined, is immutable.

**One can achieve the same effect in a more safe way**, by calling another callable unit of the language (template or function) and passing the wanted new value as an argument.

**I. Here is a simple example**. The following transformation calculates the factorial of the integer, obtained from the string value of the document (top) element of the source XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/text()" name="factorial">
    <xsl:param name="pN" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($pAccum, 1 div not($pN > 1))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()[$pN > 1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pN" select="$pN -1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum * $pN"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the following source XML document:

```
<t>9</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
362880
```

In the code above, we see how the value of the parameter `$pN` is "decreased" from call to call, until it reaches `1`, and the value of the parameter `$pAccum` is multiplied on each call by the value of the parameter `$pN`.

**Do note**, however, that we do not modify any parameter at all -- on each call a new instance of the parameter(s) is created, having the same name(s), but living only in the inner scope (call).

---

**II. Often we can avoid the need for recursion**: The following XSLT 1.0 transformation calculates and outputs the cubes of the numbers from `1` to `20`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" name="cubes">
    <xsl:param name="pN" select="20"/>

    <xsl:for-each select=
    "($vDoc//node() | $vDoc//node()/@* | $vDoc//namespace::*)
                                             [not(position() > $pN)]">
      <xsl:variable name="vM" select="position()"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="$vM*$vM*$vM"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>                                            
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any source XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1
8
27
64
125
216
343
512
729
1000
1331
1728
2197
2744
3375
4096
4913
5832
6859
8000
```

**Do note** how the standard XPath function `position()` is called to produce the "loop counter" :).  This is the well known [**method of Piez**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e300).

**Starting from XSLT versions 2.0 and above, no such tricks are necessary**. One can simply write the following, using an XPath 2.0 **[range expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-RangeExpr)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" name="cubes">
    <xsl:param name="pN" select="20"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $pN">
      <xsl:value-of select=". * . *."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>                                            
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `xsl:number` element- you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="numberVariable">
  <xsl:number/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$numberVariable * 2"/>
```

It's difficult to know exactly what you're doing from your question, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.